# Print row with minimum value in column 5 from several files

Tags: awk

How to print the row with minimum value in column 5 from several files and the name of file to each row please?

Each file has various number of rows - 20, 45, 44...

```
file0
45 7 8 9 9
45 7 5 0 5
44 5 8 9 4
11 5 6 8 8

file1
78 77 8 5 9
78 9  9 7 1
77 8 5 5 5
10 2 3 3 3
88 9 6 5 2

file2
77 8 0 0 2 
3  3 6 9 8
```

The desired result:

```
file0
45 7 5 0 5
file1
78 9 9 7 1
file2
77 8 0 0 2
```

Maybe find minimum in $5 as some variable and print a row, which included this variable in $5.

Comment: We encourage all on SO to add their efforts in their post, so kindly do so always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (Requires GNU awk):

```
$ gawk 'BEGINFILE { minline = ""; minval = 1000000 }
        $5 < minval { minline=$0; minval=$5 }
        ENDFILE { print FILENAME; print minline }' file0 file1 file2
file0
44 5 8 9 4
file1
78 9  9 7 1
file2
77 8 0 0 2
```

Set `minval` to some number that's going to be larger than any number in column 5 in any file if 1 million is too low.

Comment: Thank you very much and why is it not possible to write instead of file1 file2 file3 ...  file[1-11]

Comment: @LukášAltman You can if you want. Though `file[1-11]` expands to just `file1` which presumably isn't what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to replace file1 file2 file3 ...  file11 please?

Comment: @LukášAltman Just use whatever wildcard pattern you want that expands to the files you need. If you don't know what that means... there's probably plenty of existing questions under the [shell] tag that might help explain. Even a basic sh/bash/etc. tutorial should hopefully cover the topic, or read the documentation for your shell. It's not something really related to this question about finding the minimum rows.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: When doing min/max calculations you should just seed with the first value read, not some arbitrarily large or small number that you hope is outside the range of the data.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach , that i think could work in any `awk`, not just `gawk`:

```
awk 'FNR==1{m[FILENAME]=$5;next};$5<m[FILENAME]{m[FILENAME]=$5}END{for (i in m) print i,m[i]}' file0 file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(tested with your provided samples only).

```
awk 'FNR%2!=0{val=$0;field=$NF;next} {printf("%s\n",field>$NF?$0:val);val=""}'  file[0-2]
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program here.
FNR%2!=0{                               ##Checking condition if line number is NOT divided by 2 then do following.
  val=$0                                ##Creating variable named val and setting its value to current line.
  field=$NF                             ##creating variable field whose value is last field of current line.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  printf("%s\n",field>$NF?$0:val)       ##Printing $0 or val here depending upon condition, if field>$NF then print $0 or print val.
  val=""                                ##Nullifying variable val here.
}
'  file[0-2]                            ##Mentioning Input_file names file[0-2] means to take file0, file1 and file2 names.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please expain it to me? When I tested data I wrote here, there is no name of file and when I tested my original data there is more rows than files.

Comment: I didn't down vote but it wont produce the posted expected output from the posted sample input (it won't print the file names) and it'll only work for files that are exactly 2 lines each which is a big and probably wrong assumption (yes I know the OP provided that as the example but I strongly suspect it's a bad one).

Comment: Why is there a condition for odd lines please?

Comment: @LukášAltman because your posted sample input has exactly 2 lines per file and so that's what this solution is designed to handle. If that's not representative of your real data (e.g. your files can have 1 or 3 lines) then fix your example.

Comment: My real data have various number of rows - 20, 87, 60... Is it possible to write it in general?

Comment: Of course, it's only software so anythings possible but that'd require a different approach. When you're asking for help with parsing some input it's extremely important that you provide an example in your question that's truly representative of your real data as that's the most important thing we have to go on. Always create an example that highlights differences between data items and rainy day cases - the more effort you put into coming up with a good example that covers all your requirements and when tested against gives a pass/fail result, the more likely you'll get a good answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197175/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-ed-morton).

Comment: Great but check again that your desired output is correct given your new input as it looks wrong to me. Then just add what you've tried so far to your question and that'll probably stop the flood of downvotes and close votes.